# Unable to edit or add redirect URL's in OKTA Application

Tags: okta

I am new to OKTA and have created an OKTA Application which is OIDC client for web application to achieve SSO integration. Once i created application i am not able add or update redirect URLs to my application

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QWSh.png)

I am trying to whitelist new redirect URLS and unable to active it.
Anyone having experience in this, Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have an edit button link on the top right corner of the application "Generl Settings" tab, just above the lines in your image:

[image]

then you will be able to add/remove addresses